# Add EC2s own IP as inbound rule using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, terraform, ip

I have a license server that has a static IP set up inside the same security group and VPC as the EC2s I’m spinning up using terraform. Basically I want the license server and these EC2s to be able to communicate. At the moment they can’t because the security doesn’t add the EC2s as an inbound rule so that the license server also gets it as an inbound rule (same security group). I’m wondering how to add the IP of the EC2 I’m spinning up in terraform to the inbound of its security group so that it can talk to the license server?

Comment: So you don't know your IP address that you want to add?

Comment: No I don’t, it changes everytime the EC2 is spun up

Comment: So you want public static IP on the instance, or your local workstation?

Comment: I want to add the public IP of the EC2 to the inbound rules

Comment: Sorry, but its difficult to see what you want to achieve. Can you provide your TF code and explain why it fails and provide any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such concept as being "inside the same security group". Security Groups rules apply to each instance individually.

The correct configuration is:

- Create a Security Group for the **EC2 instances** (`EC2-SG`) that permits appropriate Inbound access to use the instance, *and*
- Create a Security Group for the **licensing server** (`License-SG`) that permits Inbound access on the licensing port from `EC2-SG`

That is, you need TWO security groups. `License-SG` will permit inbound access from any EC2 instance that has is associated with `EC2-SG`. You can have more security group as necessary for your instances -- simply add them as sources in `License-SG`.

Security Groups **can also refer to themselves**. In your current situation, where the instances and the licensing server are all associated with the *same* security group, you could add a rule that permits inbound connections from **itself**. However, this is also saying that the instances are permitting inbound connections from the licensing server, which would not be a correct configuration.

Please note that all communication within the VPC should take place via **private IP addresses**, otherwise the traffic exits the VPC and then comes in again, which does not allow Security Groups to operate correctly (and also costs you more money!).